# Iterate Through Rows of a Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Since I am a bit new to Spark Scala, I am finding it difficult to iterate through a Dataframe.
My dataframe contains 2 columns, one is `path` and other is `ingestiontime`.
Example -

[image]

Now I want to iterate through this dataframe and do the use the data in the `Path` and `ingestiontime` column to prepare a `Hive` Query and run it , such that query that are run look like -

```
ALTER TABLE <hiveTableName> ADD PARTITON (ingestiontime=<Ingestiontime_From_the_DataFrame_ingestiontime_column>) LOCATION (<Path_From_the_dataFrames_path_column>)
```

To achieve this, I used -

```
allOtherIngestionTime.collect().foreach {
  row =>
     var prepareHiveQuery = "ALTER TABLE myhiveTable ADD PARTITION (ingestiontime = "+row.mkString("<SomeCustomDelimiter>").split("<SomeCustomDelimiter>")(1)+" LOCATION ( " + row.mkString("<SomeCustomDelimiter>").split("<SomeCustomDelimiter>")(0) + ")"
      spark.sql(prepareHiveQuery)

}
```

But I feel this can be very dangerous, i.e when my Data consists of a similar Delimiter. I am very much interested to find out other ways of iterating through rows/columns of a Dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access your columns `path` and `ingestiontime` you can you `row.getString(0)` and `row.getString(1)`.

## DataFrames

```
val allOtherIngestionTime: DataFrame = ???
    allOtherIngestionTime.foreach {
      row =>
        val prepareHiveQuery = "ALTER TABLE myhiveTable ADD PARTITION (ingestiontime = "+row.getString(1)+" LOCATION ( " + row.getString(0) + ")"
        spark.sql(prepareHiveQuery)
    }
```

## Datasets

If you use **Datasets** instead of Dataframes you will be able to use `row.path` and `row.ingestiontime` in an easier way.

```
case class myCaseClass(path: String, ingestionTime: String)

val ds: Dataset[myCaseClass] = ???

ds.foreach({ row =>
  val prepareHiveQuery = "ALTER TABLE myhiveTable ADD PARTITION (ingestiontime = " + row.ingestionTime + " LOCATION ( " + row.path + ")"
  spark.sql(prepareHiveQuery)
})
```

In any case, to iterate over a Dataframe or a Dataset you can use `foreach` , or `map` if you want to convert the content into something else.

Also, using `collect()` you are bringing all the data to the driver and that is not recommended, you could use `foreach` or `map` without `collect()`

If what you want is to iterate over the `row` fields, you can make it a `Seq` and iterate:

```
row.toSeq.foreach{column => ...}
```

Comment: Thanks @Javier Monton, True, Collect() would bring all data to my driver which in case if my data is huge, will be problematic.

Comment: Monton, In case of Dataframe, when I am doing this `allOtherIngestionTime.collect.foreach { ..... } `, then its working fine, but when i am doing `allOtherIngestionTime.foreach{ ...... }` it is throwing `NullPointerException` i.e upon removing `collect()` , The code simply doesnt work. Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 2):

Check below code.

```
df
.withColumn("query",concat_ws("",lit("ALTER TABLE myhiveTable ADD PARTITON (ingestiontime="),col("ingestiontime"),lit(") LOCATION (\""),col("path"),lit("\"))")))
.select("query")
.as[String]
.collect
.foreach(q => spark.sql(q))
```